# Unable to add javascript regex in firestore rules

Tags: regex, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this rule which includes normal javascript regex written in my **FireStore Rules** tab.

```
match /anonymousUsers/{id}/{recid}{
        allow read, write: if id!=null && 
          id!="" && 
          id.matches('^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$');
}
```

But I get below token recognition error and am not able to understand why Firebase is not able to understand the regex.

> Error saving rules - Line 15: Unexpected '{'.; Line 15: token
>   recognition error at: '\'; Line 15: token recognition error at: '?';
>   Line 15: token recognition error at: '\'; Line 15: token recognition
>   error at: '?'; Line 15: token recognition error at: '\'; Line 15:
>   token recognition error at: '\'; Line 15: token recognition error at:
>   '?'; Line 15: token recognition error at: '\'; Line 15: token
>   recognition error at: '?'; Line 15: token recognition error at: '\';
>   Line 15: token recognition error at: '\'; Line 15: token recognition
>   error at: '?'; Line 15: token recognition error at: '\'; Line 15:
>   token recognition error at: '\'; Line 24: token recognition error at:
>   '\'; Line 24: token recognition error at: '\'; Line 24: token
>   recognition error at: '\'; Line 24: token recognition error at: '?';
>   Line 24: token recognition error at: '\'; Line 24: token recognition
>   error at: '?'; Line 24: token recognition error at: '\'; Line 24:
>   token recognition error at: '\'; Line 24: token recognition error at:
>   '?'; Line 24: token recognition error at: '\'; Line 24: token
>   recognition error at: '?'; Line 24: token recognition error at: '\';
>   Line 24: token recognition error at: '\'; Line 24: token recognition
>   error at: '?'; Line 24: token recognition error at: '\'

Could some please let me know what actually is missing or invalid here?

Comment: The escaping backslashes must be doubled.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Pure Genius.. :D I would like to see this as answer.. :)

Comment: I have already answered a similar question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Never mind.. Thank you so much for the help anyways.. :)